# Style Cop For Validating Markup?

Tags: .net, asp.net, standards, web-standards, stylecop

Is it possible to use StyleCop to validate the markup of an ASP.NET page or user control, to ensure the developer is following standards?

Thanks.

Comment: What kind of thing do you want to catch?

Comment: Grids on a page have paging and sorting enabled, and other common control settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This feature isn't available yet as of my last investigation.

Answer (score 1):

No. StyleCop is for C#, not HTML. You can use the built in validation inside Visual Studio.